# Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/dists/qiana/partner/binary-amd64/Packages 404 Not Found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, apt-get

I installed Linux Mint 17 Qiana (Cinamon).

When I run `sudo apt-get update`, I got output:

```
Err http://archive.canonical.com qiana/partner amd64 Packages                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]
Get:10 http://packages.linuxmint.com qiana/main i386 Packages [29,7 kB]        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
Err http://archive.canonical.com qiana/partner i386 Packages                   
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]


W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/dists/qiana/partner/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/dists/qiana/partner/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

***How to solve this trouble***

Comment: Canonical Partner repositories don't have any quiana build, just remove those entries from your sources.list.

Comment: @Braiam I executed `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` - and list is empty. How to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by clearing `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list`:

> sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list

and clear this list.

Now all work fine.